# Why does toolbar duplicate and not hide for iOS using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to apply a toolbar to android and iOs app via Xamarin.Forms. I understand that in iOS, the secondary order doesn't work the way it does for android app but my expectation is at least when toolbar items are defined, they should display horizontally. But the issue is that the toolbar is duplicated:

[image: iOs]

Here is how it displays in Android:

[image: Android]

I configured toolbar via XAML:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was sent to me in Xamarin Forums:

Hi, you don't add ToolbarItem to the TabbedPage, you need to add the ToolbarItem to each page that is going to be displayed inside of the Tab. You can find more info about ToolbarItem here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/toolbaritem.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="Microsoft.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" />
<ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="Xamarin.png" Text="Item 2" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```